# How to schedule a daily insert job in Big Query

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

What I want to do is run a daily query and insert that daily data into another table.

I am a beginner to big query and the jobs part confuses me a bit since it cannot be done through the GUI.

I read here that it should be done programmatically.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview

The problem here is that this all looks like one time jobs which cannot be automatically rescheduled. Is there any way to do this in nodejs or do I need to setup a chronjob or something to use for scheduling?

Does anybody have a good example or some pointers to get me started correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule a job in node with something like this:
[node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)
For this the node server will have to be running all time so that it can execute the job at the required time.

Alternatively you can create a cron job that calls a script which would perform the job.

Comment: If I use node-chron will this mean that node will be executed continously?
 (because server pricing is based on time that it's used) Thanks

Comment: Yes node will have to be execute continuously.